# MERN Stack - Connection - 404 - NGINX

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx

When calling an API - `http://agendamento.descopromo.tk/api/users/login` I get error 404, this call is made by a react client to a back node.I don't know where the problem is, I have little knowledge on this subject.

When I use `curl curl -d "param1 = value1 & param2 = value2" -X POST http://agendamento.descopromo.tk/api/users/login` I get the response from the validation back `{"email": "Email field is required", " password ":" Password field is required "} root @ ip-172-31-39-198`

Back Node Server.js

```
app.listen(PORT,  function() {
    console.log("Server is running on Port: " + PORT);
});
```

NGINX alterado

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
# server_name _;
  # Use below this if you need custom domain
  server_name agendamento.descopromo.tk;
  location / {
    # Connect front react
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;

}

    location ~* ^/api {
        # node api
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_send_timeout 2m;
        proxy_read_timeout 2m;
    }
}
```

````
 netstat -plant | grep 4000
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:4000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11718/node
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33112         127.0.0.1:4000          TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33126         127.0.0.1:4000          TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33130         127.0.0.1:4000          TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33124         127.0.0.1:4000          TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33122         127.0.0.1:4000          TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33114         127.0.0.1:4000          TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33110         127.0.0.1:4000          TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33116         127.0.0.1:4000          TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33118         127.0.0.1:4000          TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33128         127.0.0.1:4000          TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33120         127.0.0.1:4000          TIME_WAIT   -```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your question you're saying you connect to your API via `http://localhost:4000/api/users/login` but you add nginx config that puts your node app behind port 80 under the `/api` route. You also have two node apps running on port 3000 and 4000.

I assume you're struggling with the app running on port 4000?

```
               ┌───────┐                        
               │       │    ┌──────────────────┐
               │       │ ┌─▶│Node app port 3000│
┌───────┐      │       │ │  └──────────────────┘
│ React │─────▶│ NGINX │─┤                      
└───────┘      │       │ │  ┌──────────────────┐
               │       │ └─▶│Node app port 4000│
               │       │    └──────────────────┘
               └───────┘
```

Without more infos let me show what a complete setup could look like:

Your react app

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export function App() {
    const [user, setUser] = useState('');

    const handleLogin = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        const response = await fetch('http://yourdomain.tld/api/login', {
            //                         ^-- This address is likely different in prod vs staging
            //                         Note that this request does NOT go to port 4000 but to port 80 and requires nginx to run
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify({ user }),
        });
        const data = await response.json();

        console.log(data);
        // handle your react app response here
    };

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleLogin}>
            <input type="text" value={user} onChange={(event) => setUser(event.target.value)} />
            <button type="submit">Login</button>
        </form>
    );
}
```

Your express app

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
const port = 4000;

app.post('/api/login', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Got a POST request');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
});
```

Your nginx config

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;

    location / {
        # Connect other node app on port 3000
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_redirect          off;
        proxy_pass_header       Server;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header        X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_connect_timeout   5;
        proxy_read_timeout      240;
        proxy_intercept_errors  on;

        proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:4000;
    }
}
```

If you're running this setup locally and you **do not** run nginx (which is likley) then your react app will have to fetch from `http://localhost:4000/api/users/login`. On the server however where you do have nginx running you will have to switch that to `http://yourdomain.tld/api/login`. Use environment variables to make that switch.

Comment: And you restarted nginx?

Comment: Can you remove the `0.0.0.0` bit from your express (I assume you're using express)

Comment: yes, restart nginx, I will remove this configuration from the express

Comment: Great. Let me know if that helps. There is a lot of missing infos to really help but I'll try ;)

Comment: unfortunately the same problem 2020/08/30 01:27:33 [error] 24576 # 24576: * 5 connect () failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 179.111.179.155, server: _, request: "GET / login HTTP / 1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:4000/login", host: log nginx

Comment: Did you configure CORS?

Comment: Wait, your fetch request from react is via `/api/login` right? Do you have that route specified in your express app?

Comment: const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
 axios
    .post("http://localhost:4000/api/users/login", userData)

Comment: You just forwarded your server from `/api/*` to localhost:4000... You need to fetch from `yourdomain.tld/api/login`... provided you are running nginx locally you would fetch from `http://localhost/api/login`

Comment: but it is not correct that way http: // localhost: 4000 / api / users / login?

Comment: Well you added nginx in front of it... you can request directly from the express app but that would defeat the purpose of the nginx forward...

Comment: Dominik, I understand that you spoke, so I put the node on the same port 3000 and it worked, thanks

Comment: That's not what I was saying tho ;) You can have several node apps running on the server on different ports then then forward http requests via nginx to that port. Maybe what you had was a single app running and you thought you had to forward each route in nginx (Which you don't)... Not clear from your question

Comment: it doesn't make sense, i wrote about port, but i'm lost of what i have and doing

Comment: Not sure what your issue is. Would be good to edit your question and add more details to it

Comment: I've added more description to my answer. Hope this helps @DavidCortez

Comment: I did what you told me, I changed the call to my domain, but now I am receiving 404, but in the nestat, there are calls, thank you very much for your help                  
netstat -plant | grep 4000
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:4000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11718/node
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:60888         127.0.0.1:4000          TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:60868         127.0.0.1:4000          TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:60858         127.0.0.1:4000          TIME_WAIT   -

Comment: I read your suggestions more calmly and it worked Dominik, thank you very much

Comment: Glad it helped ;)

Comment: wow thank you x1000 @Dominik -- this saved me after 2 days of pain. 